# Breadcrumbs - problem

Tags: navigation, breadcrumbs

We have tabbed navigation: PRODUCTS, PAYMENTS, TOOLS. This tabs do not have any landing page. When user clicks on tab second level navigation opens with different links. PRODUCTS tab have 4 different links: Accounts, Cards, Deposits, Loans.

Breadcrumbs example:

Home / **Accounts**

The problem is how to show that accounts are part of PRODUCTS but there is no PRODUCTS page to click so we can not do: Home / Products / **Accounts**

Any suggestions how to show first level of navigation even if it is not clickable?

[image: Example of application]

Comment: Can you show us, design wise, what you've accomplished so far? I usually like to see people's attempts, this helps me find a better solution. Also, I'm a visual learner :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest (and probably most effective) way to solve this is to add a "products" page. Many sites that use the same navigation model you're describing also repeat the sub-menu content on the section home page. I.e. your products page becomes the home page for the products section and shows the contents of the products sub-menu with illustrative images and long form descriptions. Thus your breadcrumb link becomes valid and useful.

Comment: Just what I was thinking.